# overflow during operation a+(-a)

Tags: c++, c, binary, overflow, twos-complement

Asumming a=1

1+(-1) =0

but with 4 bit binary ,using 2's complement

0001+1111=10000 ~ 0000

Isn't signed integer overflow undefined behavior ?

Do we depend on undefined behavior for such trivial result or I am missing something .

[from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Addition):
If the left two carry bits (the ones on the far left of the top row in these examples) are both 1s or both 0s, the result is valid; if the left two carry bits are "1 0" or "0 1", a sign overflow has occurred.

Comment: Why would this be any different than 8-bit, 16-bit, etc? If you add `000...01` to `111...11` you get `000...00`.

Comment: This may help as it discusses the carry bits and overflow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Addition

Comment: When you add signed number with opposite signals, there will never be an overflow, what you are seeing is the carry number propagation to enable larger container to operate correctly.

Comment: "EDIT : from wikipedia link" which link?

Comment: When Wikipedia talks about the left two carry bits, it clearly specifies they are _not_ the ones in the far left of the top row in your examples.  Look at the Wikipedia page again for `11111 111   (carry)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding signed numbers with opposite signs never generate overflow. Indeed, hardware usually has two flag bits related to addition, i.e., overflow bit and carry bit.

Overflow bit is only set if the container is not large enough to represent the number correctly. For signed number the hardware set this bit after analyzing the sign bit of each operand and the sign of the results. If the signs of operands are differents, it will never set this bit. Otherwise, if the signals of operands are equals, it analyses the sign of result. If it is different from the operands, it set this flag, indicating that the result is in overflow.

In your example, the sign of each operand is different, so there no overflow, but this operation generate a carry bit if you want to use large container to keep operation correct.

Comment: I assumed you meant “sign” each time you wrote “signal”.

Answer (score 2):

Signed integer overflow **is** undefined, but I fail to see how this would be an issue here, since you are adding two signed numbers and the result does fall within range.

For a 4 bit integer type, overflow would be adding 7+7, where the result should be 14 that does not fit in the range -2^3..2^3-1

Comment: we know result is in range ,but at machine level adding 7+7 as 111+111=1110 is no different than adding 4+(-3) as 0100+1101=10001~0001.

Comment: @ZxcvMnb: That depends on the hardware. Whether add for a signed value will add all bits and set the carry flag or it will yield the result without modifying the carry flag is defined by the hardware.

Comment: In addition there cannot be an undefined overflow in 4-bit arithmetic because types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` and `int` is at least 16 bits wide. For smaller types/bit-fields, there is only an implementation-defined conversion from `int` to the destination type/bit-field.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: He's clearly only using 4 bits for purposes of simplicity, his question scales up with any finite number of bits.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I was considering a hypothetical architecture in which `int` might be just 4 bits (to avoid having to pull large numbers). But yes, integral types are promoted to `int` before the operation is performed.

Comment: @MooingDuck The question is tagged C, as well as being tagged with the name of another completely different language. There is no such thing as a C compiler with 4-bit ints and in any C compiler, types narrower than `int` behave differently from types wider than `int` with respect to signed overflow and its possible undefinedness (all notions that appear in the body of the question).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: And nothing in his question is specific to four bit integers _except for the particular sample_.  For instance, his question still scales up to 32 bits perfectly: "but with 32 bit binary,using 2's complement: `00000000000000000000000000000001 + 11111111111111111111111111111111 = 100000000000000000000000000000000 ~ 00000000000000000000000000000000` Isn't signed integer overflow undefined behavior ?".  Yes, 4 bit integers in C would be promoted, but the question applies to _any_ N-bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying representation may internally use overflow to get the correct result, but that is irrelevant. The behavior is only undefined if the result of an operation exceeds the range of the type.

Comment: So are you saying undefined behaviour depends on our conclusion if range was exceeded rather than bits actually overflowing ?

Comment: @ZxcvMnb From the _language_ perspective, 1+-1 doesn't overflow, so it's not undefined behavior.  What the _compiler_ or _hardware_ does is 100% irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

It is undefined behavior but I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking why it works in that example?  Because those values are within range and the result is in range.  Consider

-8 + -1

In 4 bit

1000 + 1111 -> 10111 -> 0111 -> 7.  Here we no longer have the correct answer

Comment: "it is unsigned behavior"?

Comment: Wow...terrible typo.  Should not answer questions when I'm tired.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes, fixed